# get points from database to map android

Tags: java, android

i want to show markes from my database to map android but it s five me a blank page what could i do it been 3 weeks im  stuck with that!!!help!
its the first step to get started in my project .
MY MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

// Google Map
private GoogleMap googleMap;

// Latitude & Longitude
private Double Latitude = 0.00;
private Double Longitude = 0.00;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //*** Permission StrictMode
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
    String url = "http://192.168.1.3:80/pfe/getlatLon.php";
    try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getHttpGet(url));

        location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("LocationID", c.getString("LocationID"));
            map.put("Latitude", c.getString("Latitude"));
            map.put("Longitude", c.getString("Longitude"));
            map.put("LocationName", c.getString("LocationName"));
            location.add(map);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // *** Display Google Map
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
    // *** Focus & Zoom

    Latitude =  Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("Latitude").toString());
     Longitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(0).get("Longitude").toString());
    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
     googleMap.setMapType(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 17));

    // *** Marker (Loop)
    for (int i = 0; i < location.size(); i++) {
        Latitude = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("Latitude").toString());
        Longitude =  Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("Longitude").toString());
        String name = location.get(i).get("LocationName").toString();
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new  LatLng(Latitude, Longitude)).title(name);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }

}

 public static String getHttpGet(String url) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

}

```
MY MANIFEST:




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chaima.myapplicationpfe2">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC_VseeYaw_PHdYFT4t8L1xIV0tIBszEvI" />
</application> 

</manifest>
```

MY XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/googleMap"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>


MY GRADLE:





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/googleMap"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: is the blank screen blue, by any mean ?

Comment: noo not blue white screen with a google logo in the left

Comment: screen shot would be nice

Comment: I might found the problem. do you see anything like `E/Google Maps Android API(): Authorization failure.` ?! You might have some authorization problem that's all

Comment: u ca explain more? i thought that it s caming from apikey so i change it but still not working...can u explain what u just say plz!

Comment: make sure that you put the right Hash key and app package in google console when getting the api key. otherwise you'll get this error. Also, you might be getting this error because you are testing on a release app not on a debugging app.

Comment: yes yes that s work thnks lottttttttttt brother lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `cloud console>API manager> Credentials>your MapAPI` if you don't have one then just create one.

Get your package Hash using:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

Make sure that you put the correct `Package name` and SHA-1.

**Note**
Yes you have to put 2 different SHAs for your Debugging app and your Release app

Comment: IT WOOOORKS WORKS< :D :D

Comment: Glad to hear :D, make sure you mark it as an answer for other people to use and help them

Answer (score 0):

i just like mOhemmed say ..tcheck the pakage and apikey ... this is all the code ..u can use it :D